# Iterating through an object array; foreach(var... vs. foreach(object

Tags: c#, arrays, object, foreach

```
object[] objArray = new object[]{"blah", 4, "whatever"};

foreach(var value in objArray) vs. foreach(object value in objArray)
```

I'm curious as to what the difference is between those, other than var must remain its type after assigned. Is one better than the other? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a purely functional perspective, `var` is just a shortcut for `object` here, since `objArray`'s elements are of declared type `object`.

Using `object` is a sign to whoever's reading the code that the items in the array are not known to be any type more specific than `object`. The use of `var` does not connote this. In the minimal case you posted, it really doesn't make any difference to the clarity of the program which one you use.

If, on the other hand, it is not immediately clear from the context what type of object you are working with, then it may be advantageous to explicitly declare the type. On the other hand, if the type of the elements of the collection you're iterating over is verbose and obtrusive, then it may be advantageous to use `var`, so that the reader's eyes will be drawn to the logic of the code rather than a mess of generic parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between `var` and any other type is that you let the compiler determine the type.

Answer (score 1):

there is no difference between those two,  `var` would be `object` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In your example no. But,

When declaring `objects` you get:
[Boxing and Unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)

However. When using var, it is compiled exactly as if you specified the exact type name.

So `var tempval = 5;` is the same as `int tempval = 5;`